# RC Filter component placement

Tags: filter, low-pass, passive-filter

In case of a digital signal, here is a simple RC LPF:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhtRS5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does below circuit also work as a low pass filter?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4qA3M.png)</sup>

And regarding component placement, where should the RC filter be placed close: close to the IC or close to the connector?

Comment: the second circuit is not an RC low pass filter! Can you explain what the RC is meant to filter? To first order the filter should be placed as close as possible to where the signal will be used. That way it will also filter EMI's that might have been picked-up on your PCB traces or cables.

Comment: @HervéGrabas how do you propose that the 2nd circuit wouldn't also short higher frequencies to GND? -- In the end, this very conundrum is a large part of why I personally prefer to use a "T" or "pi" filter...no question left as to orientation when your filter is symmetrical.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB No! in the ideal test case of a low pass filter were you use a voltage source on node 'Signal out from IC' you don't get high frequencies filtering. In real life you'd get attenuation because of the source impedance but that is not a proper design, you can't reliably define the cutoff frequency that way. The second circuit look more like a decoupling circuit to me. Also board designer these days would rather use 2 components than 3. The question is about LPF which is a different object than Pi filter (that prominently use ferrite anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to skip the "which side is in" controversy & simply use a "T" or "pi" filter network for RF signals.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZUkkT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Firstly, this avoids having to debate which side of the resistor to attach the capacitor to, and secondly it allows me to sneak in some "impedance matching wizardry" along with the filter, if it happens to be needed.